# Indy10 Google Securetoken always 403

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I am struggling to get a response from Google Securetoken using Delphi 10.2.2 and Indy 10.

I've gotten my RefreshToken before from https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=XXX. This worked fine.

Now I try to refresh the token with https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token, which doesn't work. I always get a `403 Forbidden` error.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    l_Response: string;
    l_PostData: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
    l_IRESAccessToken: TIRESAccessToken;
begin
    IdHTTP2.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    IdHTTP2.Request.CharSet := 'utf-8';

    l_PostData := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
    try
        l_PostData.AddFormField('grant_type', 'refresh_token');
        l_PostData.AddFormField('refresh_token', m_IRESAuth.RefreshToken);
        l_PostData.AddFormField('key', 'XXX');

        try
            l_Response := IdHTTP2.Post('https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token', l_PostData);
            l_IRESAccessToken := TJson.JsonToObject<TIRESAccessToken>(l_Response);
        except
            on E: Exception do
                ShowMessage('Error on request: '#13#10 + e.Message);
        end;
    finally
        l_PostData.Free;
    end;
end;
```

I tried an `IOHandler` that specifies TLS 1.2, and tried to send the post with a JSON object.  Also, I set the `hoKeepOrigProtocol` flag in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions`.  Nothing worked so far, I always get `403 Forbidden`.

I tried it with another program, no problems there.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you use a `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream`?

Comment: I tried it with a TStringList, JSON and TIdMultiPartFormDataStream as Parameter. Got always the same 403 Error

Answer (score 1):

Per Google's documentation:

[Token Service REST API Reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/reference/securetoken/rest/v1/token):

> HTTP request
>
> `POST https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token`
>
> Request body
>
> The request body contains data with the following structure:
>
> > URL-encoded representation
>
> `grant_type=string&code=string&refresh_token=string`

The `TStrings` overload of `TIdHTTP.Post()` sends data in that format.  That is the overload you need to use, not the `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` overload.

Also, as you can see above, this URL does not accept your `key` as input.  It only accepts `grant_type`, `code` (which is ignored when `grant_type` is not `'authorization_code'`) and `refresh_token`.

Try this instead:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  l_Response: string;
  l_PostData: TStringList;
  l_IRESAccessToken: TIRESAccessToken;
begin
  IdHTTP2.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-webform-urlencoded';

  l_PostData := TStringList.Create;
  try
    l_PostData.Add('grant_type=refresh_token');
    l_PostData.Add('refresh_token=' + m_IRESAuth.RefreshToken);

    try
      l_Response := IdHTTP2.Post('https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token', l_PostData);
      l_IRESAccessToken := TJson.JsonToObject<TIRESAccessToken>(l_Response);
    except
      on E: Exception do
        ShowMessage('Error on request: '#13#10 + e.Message);
    end;
  finally
    l_PostData.Free;
  end;
end;
```

That being said, after reading the above documentation, I don't believe you can send an `idToken` from `https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword` to `https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token` as a `refresh_token`.  I think you need to send it as an `authorization_code` instead, which then gives you a `refresh_token`.  So try adding that extra step, if you have not already done so.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response and thank you for the answer.

After consultation with the Main-API-Developer, he told me that they are using Firebase in the background. So the API request für Google is different.

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/use-rest-api#section-sign-in-email-password
https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/use-rest-api#section-refresh-token

With this missing information the request works fine

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    l_Response: string;
    l_IRESAccessToken: TIRESAccessToken;

    l_Json: string;
    l_JsonToSend: TStringStream;
begin
    l_Json := '{"grant_type": "refresh_token","refresh_token": "'+ m_IRESAuth.RefreshToken+ '"}';
    l_JsonToSend := TStringStream.Create(l_Json, TEncoding.UTF8);
    try
        try
            l_Response := IdHTTP2.Post('https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=XXX, l_JsonToSend);
            l_IRESAccessToken := TJson.JsonToObject<TIRESAccessToken>(l_Response);
        except
            on E: Exception do
                ShowMessage('Error on request: '#13#10 + e.Message);
        end;
    finally
        l_JsonToSend.Free;
    end;
end;
```